# Verb forms -s -ing (future tense)

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, tense, future-tense

Can I use the -s and -ing form interchangeably if I'm talking about something in the future?

Person A:

*Do you know when David gets his car back from the dealership?*

*Do you know when David is getting his car back from the dealership?*

Person B:

*He gets it back tomorrow.*

*He is getting it back tomorrow.*

Person A:

*Do you think Blaire can get pregnant again?*

Person B:

*I don't think there is a chance Blair ever gets pregnant again.*

*I don't think there is a chance of Blair getting pregnant again.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These sentences are actually all in present tense: we often use present tense to express future events.

We  can [present continuous](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentcontinuous.html) form **getting** to talk about things that we are expecting to happen in the future, even if we are not sure exactly when they will happen.

We can also use [present simple](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-m_future-sp.htm) to talk about future event, but usually we only do this when we are talking about things that are scheduled or timetabled:

> David's plane arrives at 07:45
>   The concert starts at 7pm.

Looking at your first example, about the car, present continuous is better because David getting his car back is not a timetabled event, however you will also hear people using present simple for this kind of dialog.

The second example is somewhat confusing because you use the word **can** which means **is able to**. Assuming that's what you meant, here is the question and answer.

> Do you think that Blaire can get pregnant again?
>   No, I don't think that she can.

If you wanted to ask whether it is **likely** that Blaire will get pregnant again, I think that the future simple is better:

> Do you think that Blaire will get pregnant again?
>   I don't think that there is a chance that Blair will ever get pregnant again.